# How to add a image at the center of a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view

I have a TableLayout with some tablerow like this:

[image]

I want to add a image over the above layout under the circular mark as mention below:

[image]

Here is my layout code:

```
   <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/img1_1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/img1_2"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_margin="3dp" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/img1_3"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
   />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/img1_4"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_margin="3dp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

So how to add a image over this layout at the center position?

Comment: I would use a FrameLayout and layer the image above the TableLayout and then just assign gravity to the image

Comment: Can u gave me a sample because I have already tried frameLayout ,but problem is in layering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="biw.myapplication.MainActivity">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/table1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/img1_1"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/img1_2"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_margin="3dp" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/img1_3"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/img1_4"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_margin="3dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

It's worth noting that you should look into the difference between `gravity` and `layout_gravity`, `gravity` assigns the alignment of the widget within the layout, whereas `layout_gravity` assigns the alignment to the layout itself.

Also, this code only works if you assign a static width and height to the image.

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this structure

```
<FrameLayout>
<TableLayout></TableLayout>
<ImageView android:layout_gravity="centre"/>
</FrameLayout>
```